# Weekly comic story about aliens trying to conquer Earth by winning the World Cup

Tags: story-identification

UK comic in 1970's.
I was outlining this to grandson but few details are left in my mind.
There was usually three or four pages.  They had grey flat heads and wore track suits or red football (soccer for USA) kit when playing football.

There was some military planning mistake and they thought if they won the World Cup they would rule Earth.

Most weeks it was a story from foreign countries about a national game - usually to show locals and their customs could seem alien as well.

They had a human manager and coach. Usually they managed a winning goal in the closing seconds.

The media pack who travelled with them were often told of their forthcoming conquest but treated it as a joke. "Taking their football very seriously"

Comment: I don't suppose any of [these](http://blog.crystal-knights.co.uk/category/1970s/) looks familiar?

Comment: This reminds me of the blancmange aliens who tried to win Wimbledon.

Comment: I've scrolled through the list but can't see the strip I remember. I want to say 1972 but it could be later than that

Comment: I wonder if this was one of the story arcs in 2000 AD

Comment: @John Rennie. Thinking back it was probably in one of the 'classic' UK comics in the seventies.  Something like Victor, Hotspur, Rover et al.

Comment: Heh. That almost sounds like a plot from a Billy the Fish strip in Viz Magazine.